# Finding the area between two curves using a set of transforms and their Jacobian

Tags: multivariable-calculus, transformation, multiple-integral

I have the following transforms:

$\begin{align}
x &= u^2 - v^2 \\
y &= 2uv
\end{align}$

and am tasked with finding the area between the following curves:

$\begin{align}
x &= 4 - \frac{y^2}{16} \\
x &= \frac{y^2}{4} - 1
\end{align}$

So, I substituted the transforms into the equations for the curves:

$\begin{align}
u^2 - v^2 &= 4 - \frac{4u^2v^2}{16} \\
u^2 - v^2 &= \frac{4u^2v^2}{14} - 1
\end{align}$

Solving the first for $u$ and the second for $v$, I get:

$\begin{align}
u &= \pm2 \\
v &= \pm1
\end{align}$

And figure the area between these two curves must be:

$\begin{align}
4 \int_{-1}^1 \int_{-2}^2 (u^2 + v^2) \,du \,dv
\end{align}$

Solving this, I end up at $\frac{160}{3}$; my books says I should end up at $\frac{50}{3}$

Am I misunderstanding how to use transforms and the Jacobian to find the area between two curves, or does it look like I've made a mistake somewhere in my algebra?

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
  x &= \left( \frac{y}{2v} \right)^{2}-v^{2} \\
    &= u^{2}-\left( \frac{y}{2u} \right)^{2}
\end{align*}

Note that $(u,v) \in [0,2] \times [0,1]$ (blue and red grids) has already covered half of the area (green) below:

[image]

Avoid double count, either take $(u,v) \in [0,2] \times [-1,1]$ or $[-2,2] \times [0,1]$

\begin{align*}
  dA &= 4(u^2+v^2) \, du \, dv \\
  A &= \int_{-1}^{1} \int_{0}^{2} 4(u^2+v^2) \, du \, dv \\
    &= \int_{-1}^{1} \left[ \frac{4u^{3}}{3}+4uv^{2} \right]_{u=0}^{2} dv \\
    &= \int_{-1}^{1} \left( \frac{32}{3}+8v^2 \right) dv \\
    &= \left[ \frac{32v}{3}+\frac{8v^{3}}{3} \right]_{v=-1}^{1} \\
    &= \frac{80}{3}
\end{align*}